# Set more than one DNS in NetworkManager

Tags: linux, unix, networkmanager, wicd

I want to set 4 DNSs, but NetworkManager just has one field for DNS! I tried to add my DNS into `/etc/resolve.conf` but when I reboot my pc this file reset to defualt! Is there any way to set more than one DNS into NetworkManager? Just like WICD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the tooltip says, separate the DNS server addresses by commas. Do note that most resolvers won't use [more than 3 DNS servers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28004/how-to-overcome-libc-resolver-limitation-of-maximum-3-nameservers) though.