# Is it possible to add/change DNS server without having to drop existing connections?

Tags: dns, unix, networkmanager

I just changed (or [added](https://superuser.com/a/606547/187555) another) DNS server to my network connection configuration and would like to use it straight away, but I have a few existing (mostly SSH) connections open that I don't want to lose, so restarting the network interface seems risky.

Is there a way to just apply the change to any new connections I initiate from here on?

Answer (score 0):

Bypass NetworkManager for now and directly add the new servers either through `resolvectl` if that's in use, or to the `/etc/resolv.conf` file otherwise.